# Drupal 8 Internal Redirect

Tags: redirect, drupal, internals

How would I go about implementing an internal dynamic redirect in Drupal 8?

For example lets say my url is "/toy" but internally it needs to be routed to "/filters/toys".

Thanks!

Comment: Drupal would call these an alias, I think.

Comment: Yeah I need to do internally.

Comment: @Jeremy you'll have to provide more info. What is 'toy'?, What is '/filters/toys'? Is this a view? Are those contextual filters? Is this a page that just needs another alias?

Answer (score 1):

You can use module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect):

1. Install and enable module
2. Go to `Configuration` > `Search and metadata` > `URL redirects`
3. Click `Add redirect`, enter old path and new path you want redirect to:
   [image]

4. Then `Save`